# I would need help with how to translate an easy Russian word in IPA

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am doing some home work and would need help with two names that I can not find. What is Эва and яна in IPA?

Comment: generally, Яна is a female name. But this, sure, can be something other depending on the context

Comment: It could also be genitive of Ян, which is male name.

Comment: Could you provide more context? It is hard to tell what is `Эва`. It can be a peculiar spelling of `Ева` (Eve, like Adam and Eve), but I'm not sure. By the way what is "IPA"?

Comment: yes, it might be Eva, I'm not sure what is correct in English Eve or Eva. If we are talking about the female name Eva or Eve, then I can tell you that we usually write in Russian `Ева` and not `Эва`, `Е` and `Э` are different letters which designate different sounds. `Е` is pronounced like `ye`in "yes", "yesterday" and `Э` like `a` in "mad"

Comment: `Е` is **USUALLY** pronounced like `ye` in "yes", "yesterday" and `Э` like a in "mad". There are exceptions

Comment: Would Эва in IPA be: ['ævə]?

Comment: though I still do not know what is IPA, but as I understand English transcriptions, yes, Эва would be ['ævə]

Comment: Would Яна be [janə']?

Comment: no, it would be [ˈjɑnɑ], and I mean [jɑ] or ['ja] (as you wrote it) is like "ya" in yankee. Though, I think you can pronounce it like ['janə] but the emphasis must be on the first syllable.

Comment: but the emphasis **in both cases** must be on the first syllable.

Comment: @user907860 For crying out loud, *э* is pronounced nothing like *a* in *mad*.

Comment: @user907860 And... [ˈjɑnɑ]? Really? I don't want to get confrontational, but you seem to have a difficulty separating phonetics from spelling, and you've given some very confusing, and thoroughly wrong, answers to a rather basic question.

Comment: @Ershov: Kindly, please update me on what the correct answers would be in this cases.

Comment: Sorry, see below. Just had to double-check first because with [e] and [ɛ] I keep forgetting which is which.

Comment: @NikolayErshov, I'm not a linguist, I just looked into a dictionary for any word which has "ya" at the start, and it is Yana [ˈjɑːnə] (I did not spot the ending of this, only the first syllable) сущ.; геогр. Яна (река в России, в Якутии). Then I took [jɑ] and gave my answer. So what's wrong with that? Then I said that  [jɑnə] is correct, except the emphasis.

Comment: *э is pronounced nothing like a in mad.* Really? I don't know, may be you speak some different Russian, but in mine `э` is pronounced nothing like `a` in mad, cat, fat and so on.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Well as it happens, I'm not a linguist either, and I freely admit I've had my share of embarrassing "why did I think I knew what I was talking about?" episodes, and I'd like to think I've learned from them. Both [ɑ] and the length marking mean that the particular dictionary you looked into was using a different notation from IPA. [ɑ] in IPA is a "yawning" kind of /a/ that's definitely not the vowel in `Яна`. And if for you `э` matches the vowel in "mad" or "cat", then I'm afraid it must be you who speak some different English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Яна** is ['janə] and **Эва** is ['ɛvə].

Comment: Can you recommend a reference besides the IPA page so that I do not have to pester people and waste everyone's time with simple questions?

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty sure that you are a more significant authority than abby lingvo

Comment: @user907860 well, I'm in all modesty inclined to think I can provide more useful input on IPA than someone who started by asking what IPA is.